# Layer intersection using ArcGIS Server with Flex/REST APIs?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3, arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-flex-api

I'm trying to implement an intersection with ArcGIS 9.3.1, flex and rest api.

I have two layers. I query the first one that returns a Graphic object. With this Geometry I want to query a second layer with an intersection.

The problem is that the second query returns all the features even outside the intersection geometry.

Is there an example somewhere on the internet?

Comment: From where are you doing this? ArcDesktop/ArcObjects/REST APIs/JSON? According to the Rest APIs the query takes a geometry, so what you are trying to do should be possible: http://www.esri.com/industries/landing-pages/geoservices/geoservices.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the geometry from your first query as the geometry parameter in your second query. I know you said flex, but here's a JavaScript sample showing this:  http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/query_bypoly.html

If there's a flex sample showing how to do this, it's probably here:  http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/samples/index.html

Also, here's the REST documentation for the query endpoint:  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/query.html